# SVN rename folder Access denied, but only on my machine

Tags: svn

If I right-click on a folder in my project and do an TortoiseSVN->Rename, it thinks a while and then tells me `Can't move X to Y: Access Denied`. But from a colleagues machine it works ok, and I can do rename *files* no problem. What gives?

Comment: SVN rename works on your local directory, not the server, so any issues are related to your local computer. For example, it might be that you have the directory (or some file) opened in some application, which prevents it from being deleted.

Comment: Agreed, that's likely it. It might be the Tortoise SVN Cache helper process - you can try killing to see if that fixes it. Otherwise rebooting will almost certainly fix it. Or maybe you did something in that folder from a Run-as-Administrator command prompt or process? Try using an administrator prompt to rename it, or icacls to grant permission back to yourself.

Comment: Sometimes, your editor or IDE locks a folder when your last open file was there (even after you close the file). You can also use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to look for open handles.

Comment: I have had the same problem and it's very frustrating.  In my case, it partially does the move, so I have to revert the added files and do a clean up and then do the rename again and it works.  I agree with the above comment that says it's likely to be the Tortoise SVN Cache helper process, but I haven't found any consistent way to prevent the problem.

Comment: Is it happens to the path length? I had my project in root of drive and could rename, but my colleague couldn't rename because he had same project on a 5 level folder

Comment: Fixed it with a reboot. Just closing IDEs and apps did not fix it for me.

Answer (score 17):

As suggested in the comments, the problem could be that the folder or one of its contained items is open. See [How do you find what process is holding a file open in Windows?](https://serverfault.com/q/1966/171233) for ways to find out what's locking the files.

Comment: In the last months Subversion renames fail systematically for me. A handle search in Process Explorer by Systernals shows that Windows Explorer itself keeps like a dozen handles open for no obvious reason. I wonder if something changed either in TortoiseSVN or Windows :_(

Answer (score 15):

I've had success overcoming this by throwing the folder I want to rename into the trash, checking the folder out in SVN, and then renaming it.

Comment: worked for me too. But i also had some unversioned *.bak files in my folders.

Answer (score 6):

I just had success by doing the rename from the 'Repository Browser' window, then Update in my working copy.

Comment: It just happened to me and the problem wouldn't go away even after a reboot. Oddly, even within the same folder, Tortoise would rename some files without a problem but wouldn't rename other files. Eventually, I fixed the problem by doing the same as you did (Repo browser, rename, and Update). Before that, I tried several methods including copy / delete / rename back to the initial name and then Tortoise rename, but I always got the error message. It was only those specific names that refused to be renamed. Other names could be renamed by Tortoise without a problem.

Comment: ... And it had nothing to do with the length of the path, because some files inside the folders that couldn't be renamed could be renamed without a problem.

Comment: I solved as you said. After updating, the working copy had **both folders, new and old**. Maybe the rename wasn't possibile for a few file that where not in the repository (e.g. some temporary or bak file in my case... that's the only content of the old folder).

Comment: Can confirm this to work in my case on Windows 10 Pro x64: The workaround through rename in "Repository Browser" and Update of working copy finally solved the issue! Nothing else helped: Clean up of working copy, reboot, ...

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded by moving the folder (via explorer and drag'n'drop) to a location outside my project, then moving it back to the original location inside my project. After that, renaming using TortoiseSVN worked as expected.

Comment: This worked for me as well: Cut the folder > Paste it in a different folder > Move it back to the original location > TortoiseSVN rename works! ...it's kind of odd that renaming via Windows File Explorer worked before that but the TortoiseSVN rename did not.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Windows 10.  The issue for me was that the "Quick Access" in Windows Explorer was showing the directory that I wanted to move as recently viewed.  When I removed the directory from Quick Access, SVN was able to move the directory.  Sam's answer helped me track this down with Windows Resource Monitor.